# Display all users(directly or indirectly) under a manager - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I have a emp table as follows:

```
userID varchar(10)
ManagerID varchar(10)
```

Data:

```
UserID    ManagerID
101         102
103         102
104         103
```

I need to find all the users under a manager directly or indirectly.

The output should be as follows:

If it is for 102:

```
Manager     ReportingUsers
--------------------------
102           101,103
```

And if we check for 104 the output should be:

```
Manager     ReportingUsers
--------------------------
104         102,101,103 `
```

The query I am writing for achieving this is as follows

```
SELECT managerID, GROUP_CONCAT(userID) FROM emp GROUP BY managerID;
```

But the output I get satisfies the first output but not the second:

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| MANAGERID | GROUP_CONCAT(USERID) |
+-----------+----------------------+
| 102       | 101,103              |
| 104       | 102                  |
+-----------+----------------------+
```

How do I achieve this use case using Cursors and Stored Procedures through which I can get the output for every manager?

Just an update If I use the below query I get the result for my second example as well but the first example for 102 does not get satisfied:

```
SELECT m.MANAGERID,  GROUP_CONCAT(m.USERID,';',(Select Group_Concat(n.USERID) from emp as n where m.userID=n.managerID or n.managerID=NULL group by n.managerID)) as ReportingUsers FROM emp as m GROUP BY managerID;
```

If I can get a solution using cursors and procedures that would also work.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is not a `sql-server` function. Did you mean `MySQL`? Can you please update your question using the right tags?

Comment: Apologies. I am new to SQL. I would be grateful if you can give me a sql-server query also for this.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you [Mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, it gives the expected output:

```
mysql> select * from testdb.hierarchy;
+--------+-----------+
| userID | managerID |
+--------+-----------+
| 101    | 102       |
| 103    | 102       |
| 104    | 103       |
+--------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select managerID, group_concat(userID) from hierarchy group by managerID ;
+-----------+----------------------+
| managerID | group_concat(userID) |
+-----------+----------------------+
| 102       | 101,103              |
| 103       | 104                  |
+-----------+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This only satisfies my first use case and not the second one. under 103 I want to show 104 along with 101 and 103 as they have indirect reporting as well.

Comment: sorry, my bad, i missed your "indirect" connection between user and a "2nd level" manager, i'll edit my answer soon

Answer (score 0):

You might consider switching to a nested set model:

```
user_id lft rgt
    102   1   8
    101   2   3
    103   4   7
    104   5   6
```

Otherwise, confirm which database/version you're using.

Comment: I am using MYSQL version 5.5.62